# Add Text to WooCommerce Product Page Based on metadata using hooks

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, metadata, product

I have products that allow for bidding, but no function that informs the customer about the minimum increment value for the actual bidding.

So, I need help in getting the `meta_key` and `meta_value` of that `key` and display the result of the `value`, **unless** empty.

**Meaning**: if the input field is set to **100**, the `meta_value` of the `meta_key` is `100`.

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = '_bid_increment' AND meta_value = ''
```

That explains what I need, but the value of the `meta_value` is based on the field input for `_bid_increment`, and I do not know how to get it.

**My plan is this:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form',  'bid_increment_is' );
function bid_increment_is() {
echo '<div class="increment-for-this-product-is">The minimum increment for this product is: ????</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the product object. Then using `get_meta()` method with the correct meta key, you will get the desired value:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form',  'bid_increment_is' );
function bid_increment_is() {
    global $product;

    $meta_value = $product->get_meta('_bid_increment');

    if ( ! empty($meta_value) ) {
        printf( '<div class="increment-for-this-product-is">The minimum increment for this product is: %s</div>', $meta_value );
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Huge thank you!